# $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I solve this without L'Hospital?

I was going to try to multiply by conjugate 2 times, but I already gave up. I also tried to multiply by the conjugate above and below (x) + and ^ -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$e^x=1+x+{x^2\over 2}+O(x^3)$$

Comment: Thank you! :) ..

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!