# What is $\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right)$ without l'Hopital's rule?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, functions

Any ideas on how to calculate $\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right)$ without using l'Hopital's rule?

I tried putting $u = e^x-1$ and $x = \ln(u+1)$, replacing but i dont get much farther than that.
I wanted to use the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x = e$ along to solve it but dont know how.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{u \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{\ln(u+1)}\right) = \lim_{u \to 0} \left(\frac{\ln(u+1)-u}{u\cdot \ln(u+1)}\right) $$

If the $u$ multiplying in the denominator were to be $ \frac{1}{u} $, I could make $\frac{1}{u} \cdot \ln(u+1) = \ln(u+1)^\frac{1}{u}$ and do $t = \frac{1}{u} $ (with $ {u \to 0} $ implying $ {t \to \infty} $) and $ \ln(u+1)^\frac{1}{u} = \ln(\frac{1}{t} + 1)^t $.
Then $ \lim_{t \to \infty} \ln(\frac{1}{t} + 1)^t = \ln(\lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{t} + 1)^t\right) = \ln(e) = 1 $.
That is as far as I got.

Comment: You need to show your effort for what you've tried to answer the question. This isn't a homework service website.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Can you use $e^x-1-x\sim\frac12x^2$?

Comment: @J.G. Hi, thanks! i dont think so, it's a calculus 1 course problem.

Comment: @creepshow Welcome to stack exchange. If you show what you have done so far, we will help you. As Adam said, this isn't a homework service. We need to know that you have actually put effort into the problem before posting it.

Comment: @DylanLevine thanks, i didnt know. i already edited how i thought to solve it

Comment: @creepshow Welcome. Try to follow JG's comment above to find the limit $-0.5$ If you know  l'hopital's rule,and $e$ it self, you must know too that approximation of $e$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3348754/lim-x-to-0-left-frac1x-frac1ex-1-right?noredirect=1

Comment: @Piquito I think that is a very general assumption to make. I just finished AP Calc AB and I know about L'Hopital's rule and about $e$ but the approximation is unfortunately not in the curriculum.

Comment: It has a "duplicate" closing vote. It's strictly true, but, what if the answers for the older question are not satisfactory? (I think they are not and, anyway, this is reasonably opinable). The "lack of..." closing votes seem to be premature as the OP edited the question in a fashion that can be considered acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The substitution you tried can't help so much, instead we can try with

$$\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x} =\frac{x-e^x+1}{x(e^x-1)}=-\frac{x}{e^x-1}\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}$$

which reduces to the standard limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}x$ and to

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}$$

which is discussed here

- [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/387333/505767)

---

Note that the way you were looking for by substitution leads to a similar solution indeed from here

$$\ldots=\frac{\ln(u+1)-u}{u\cdot \ln(u+1)}=\frac{u}{\ln (1+u)}\frac{\ln(1+u)-u}{u^2}$$

which reduces to the standard limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}x$ and to

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}$$

which is discussed in the same reference.

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: Please post your own answer! I can delete that one.Bye

Comment: No, please keep it up. I was just joking and your answer is much better than mine would have been

Comment: how do i get the first step? because i cant make the denominator. i had e^x-1 but in the denominator there it is e^x+1

Comment: maybe i'm not seeing it but i think the first two expressions on the first equal are not equal

Comment: @creepshow It was a typo, now fixed. By substitution you were going in a similar solution.I add something on that.

Comment: thanks, although now i'm having lots of problems understanding the fist response of the reference. the second response there is not going to be useful because in the course we haven't seen binomial theorem.

Comment: @creepshow Then you can refer to the method by substitution,using the limit with $\log$. Is that way clear to you?

Comment: @user for instance, in the reference, when its solving L4, how do they make it to the second step? i think when they write "4L4" its because they multiply by 4 the limit but i just dont make sense of the multiplication :(

Comment: @creepshow They are plugging $2x$ instead of $x$ nad the $4$ comes out form the denominator.

Comment: @creepshow He made the change of variable $x\to 2x$, then got rid of the 4 in the denominator multiplicating the limit by 4.

Comment: oh! i didnt see it. thanks you so much!

Comment: then i'm already lost from step 2 to step 3

Comment: @creepshow He calculated $3L_4=4L_4-L_4$ from the previous values (then, again a variable change, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotics ... As $x \to 0$,
\begin{align}
e^x &= 1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2 + o(x^2)
\\
e^x-1 &= x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2) = x\left(1+\frac{1}{2}x + o(x)\right)
\\
\frac{1}{e^x-1} &= \frac{1}{x}(1-\frac{1}{2}x + o(x))
= \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2} + o(1)
\\
\frac{1}{e^x-1} - \frac{1}{x} &= -\frac{1}{2} + o(1)
\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{e^x-1} - \frac{1}{x}\right) &= -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: The OP mentiones in the comments that Taylor polynomials cannot be used. Furthermore, this solution has already been given in the duplicate questions.